# Tags in put with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use the https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ library.

I want to create a container where a user can type tags and when they press enter it should be transformed into a tag. (think stackoverflow tags)

There should probably be a hidden input which contains a list of the tags

Like this:

[image]

Is there another library or is there a way to do it?

Comment: This has to be done via javascript. I reccomend looking at jQuery for this sort of task.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBaMvM here's the css and method of how stack overflow do it.

Comment: https://select2.github.io/ does almost the same and it's easy to use.

Comment: The thing is, i need text AND tags. The given examples only accept tags...